# SKErrorPaymentCancelled called even nothing cancelled

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

yesteday i tested in app purchase without any problems. And today as i try to make a payment, the request start and then the failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction is called with SKErrorPaymentCancelled.
My iPad is correctly connected. 
I forgot! this is happelning WITHOUT cancelling any transaction !

an idea ?
thanks

Comment: Please provide more detail about you product type.

Comment: I have the same issue.  It used to work.  I had to rebuild the project now it returns the same error even though there is no cancelation.

Comment: Same issue. It used to work fine. Bug from apple!